# xml file overriding notification bar

Tags: java, android

please help me out. whats wrong in this code and why actionsupportbar() is not working.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class chatWin extends AppCompatActivity {
    String reciverimg, reciverUid,reciverName,SenderUID;
    CircleImageView profile;
    TextView reciverNName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_win);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.recivername), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });



        reciverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("nameeee");
        reciverimg = getIntent().getStringExtra("reciverImg");
        reciverUid = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");

        reciverNName = findViewById(R.id.recivername);
        profile = findViewById(R.id.profileimgg);

        Picasso.get().load(reciverimg).into(profile);
    }
}
```

i am expecting what sort of changes should be required in my code so that it should not override the notification bar and how the actionsupportbar will work with no errors.